# Connect vertex after bevel

Tags: edges, bevel

help me out pls. I did a bevel and trying to add edges between vertex that is not connected to keep right shape of polygons, but i see this strange thinks and i am pritty sure that something went wrong. I choose 2 vertex and press F button, where am i wrong? Thx

[image]

Comment: If you could provide an image of the before and the after or maybe highlight which part of your screenshot is the area of interest, it would be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Knife tool (K) instead to cut more edges. I'm new to Blender too, but it seems that F (make edge/face) is for building up new mesh in space, not for cutting new edges in existing geometry. When you choose two vertices and make an edge between them with F, it doesn't seem as if the new edge is connected to the face it crosses.  Correct me if I'm wrong someone.

Comment: the knife, or simply press J to join 2 vertices, and you're right about F   ;)